# Ubuntu 14.4 and macbook

Tags: macbook

I installed Ubuntu on my macbook 2009. The install is almost completely working. But I encountered an issue with my wifi, which does not work. All other things work well such as my NIC, display, desktop environment, keyboard. Can someone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Have you run the "Additional Drivers" wizard? http://www.howtogeek.com/213488/how-to-install-hardware-drivers-on-linux/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.